10 year old dealing with ADHD or Autism-like symptoms and introducing management techniques
I need to lead this with the fact that there is no official diagnosis yet - this is merely initial comparisons made by school counsellors.
So it has been suggested that my 10 year old son is dealing with a lack of awareness regarding:

understanding his emotions, and emotional expression - he gets visibly frustrated/angry at things, but claims he is "fine".
recognising certain behaviours; he claims he is being bullied "by everyone" for being "weird", when he has a rather intense energy, especially when his emotions are heightened; has very little to no spacial awareness, often getting very close to others; and acting like a "puppy" with any one he looks up to/treats him nicely (getting close, assuming a happy "begging" stance). This is more common with strangers or acquaintances, rather than close friends or relatives, and primarily adults (perhaps figures of authority?).
recognising his own contributions to conflicts. For example, he may be frustrated at something, and an unrelated input may frustrate him further, causing him to lash out, and causing a conflict. When the person affected retaliates, that's when there is a problem - he "did nothing", and they acted out towards him for "no reason".
He prefers natural light, (preferring darker light levels) over artificial light, and can get easily overstimulated with light levels, noise and cramped conditions
Constant pacing when unoccupied, unless interrupted. He again sees nothing wrong with this behaviour, even though this consistently leads to frustration of having nothing to do, and not wanting to do anything, aside from constant screen time (Minecraft or Mario Kart, YouTube, iPad games, etc).
Impulse control is a big one - constantly stealing snacks and drinks, or to play games or on his iPad, and makes efforts to wake up early (setting his alarm for 5.30) in order to attempt this, or actively hides his actions (usually by hiding the evidence in his room).
When he has trouble sleeping, he simply turns lights on, regardless of how many times he is told not to do this, and ask for music or grey/white noise (rain sounds or running water) instead, which to relax him and keep him calm, rather than keep him more awake.
Constant asking for the same things, only remembering when he has been told "later", and never when he has been told "no".

Efforts we have made to help or control this (as well as suggestions we have been given):

fidget toys, and to encourage their use when calm, to help create a sense of calming for when he is agitated
physical activity, like running around, kicking a ball, jumping on the trampoline, which he often refuses. He is currently enrolled in a martial arts class once a week, which he very much enjoys, but when it's suggested he practice his "set" at home, he refuses as well.
reading to help calm before bed (has only recently been getting into one book, which has been difficult in the past), but he only does this when he wants to, when he is not in the "bored" mindset.
limiting screen time; we do currently limit screen time to 1 hour, regardless of type and end all screen time half an hour before bed, but allow more over the weekend, extending it to a few hours depending on what is happening.
talking him through conflicts and helping him become aware of his own actions, emotions and expressions, however this often causes him to become more upset, leading him to blame and put himself down.

These are only new adjustments, so the resistances and responses are understandable, and we have been told that he will struggle with these behaviours throughout his teenage years. We do have another 12 year old who is beginning to enter his teenage phase, already reaching puberty, dealing with peer pressures, his own obsessions and resistance to rules and restrictions, etc., making this new adjustment particularly straining on us as parents.
Are there any tactics we can employ to help adopt these techniques?
Additionally, I want to introduce him to the concept of his antics. As an example, I have Epilepsy, and before this diagnosis when I was 25 (roughly 10 years ago), I was unable to understand what was going on - a lack of focus, or an inability to comprehend conversation at times; getting "dizzy spells" and nausea, and lapses in memory. Once I received this diagnosis, these symptoms made sense, making it less frustrating and easier to manage and adjust.
Introducing him to his (potential) condition may help his understanding, but I am hesitant because this diagnosis is not official (we are waiting on an appointment with a Paediatrician), and the potential of identifying as "Autistic". Again, as an example, I see my self as "myself; with Epilepsy" - this is not who I am as a person, this is just an aspect of my physiology, in the same way that I am shortsighted - I simply need to manage this; as opposed to "being an Epileptic", and defining my life through these restrictions.
I want to ask if I should do this, though that will potentially draw opinions - I am uncertain. But if I do, how should I go about this with a young, impressionable mind?

There's a lot of issues here; I'm afraid this will be closed for either being too broad (too many questions) or opinion based. There's also a few medical issues at play here, risking unfounded diagnoses/guesses. Are you familiar with "emotional literacy"? Have you employed this with your kids? Why doesn't he start off the sleep routine with a white noise machine? Are there external consequences for sneaking in game time? Or "stealing"? So many questions... Too many, really.

I agree, there are multiple questions and it's not completely clear what you're trying to accomplish. You'll need to edit the question to make it less broad.

Is this the same son that did get a diagnosis months ago? https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/adressing-introducing-autism

Initially this opinion was posted as a series of comments to an answer provided here, but it may possibly apply as well as an answer, so here is the opinion.
Have your child undergo a neuropsychiatric evaluation as soon as you are able, let his teacher(s) know his behavior is being evaluated, and that you hope to have an effective, coordinated approach soon. You'll keep them informed, and until then, you'll address each issue as best as you can. Really, with so very many different behaviors to address, there's no one answer, and it's the best you can do.

I appreciate that there's a stigma attached, unjustly, to many labels, so it's right that this should be considered. However, labels also have a positive side: an approach to treatment that may be more organized and effective than treating each component individually. Recognized here is that I have a bias towards diagnosis; in physical illnesses, there is often a constellation of symptoms, some that have been recognized by the patient/healthcare provider, and some which they might not have considered, but on reflection, find are present.
For example, a child with ankylosing spondylitis may have pain misdiagnosed as 'growing pains", back pain as poor sleeping habits/positions/surfaces/lack of exercise/core strength, weight loss as poor appetite, a stooped position as poor posture, etc. However, a blood test will label the cause of all these symptoms and will often replace unhelpful piecemeal advice (and judgements) with the correct underlying cause and treatment. Conditions of psychological origin can also benefit from labels in helping to establish a more coordinated and effective treatment of the underlying cause.
Only judgemental people attach stigma to labels; the less attention we pay to their judgements, the less validity we give them, then the less we incorporate them into who we are. Just as a child with ankylosing spondylitis is not less of a valuable person because of their condition, so to with conditions of (increasingly recognized to be of genetic origin) neuropsychiatric conditions. A child might go from being negatively judged to be noisy and unmanageable to being understood to have a particular variant of, say, ADHD. The whole picture is worth considering. What is most helpful?
As you stated, you consider epilepsy to be part of who you are, not the definition of who you are. It was actually a relief to have a "label" to explain some of your puzzling symptoms.
Right now, your post does outline your son's "symptoms" as being negative: a lack of understanding/insight and regulation of emotions, poor impulse control, stealing, deceit, blame shifting (oops, my reading, not your complaint), poor memory, etc.
To my reading, this is a constellation of behaviors that suggest an underlying condition, one which must be recognized as such to have a coordinated and effective approach to treatment (your responses, etc.) A professional is needed here for both the diagnosis of and treatment approach to a potential neuropsychiatric condition. This will not only help you in your understanding and approach, replacing some of your (and his teacher(s)'s frustrations with understanding, but it wil also relieve your son of the burden of some unjust judgements on the part of others, helping some of his already bruised self-esteem issues (e.g. lashing out is usually an attempt to protect self-esteem.)
The sooner this whole constellation of behaviors is recognized as one condition (or possibly two), the sooner he and everyone around him can start to understand why his behavior is not simply a bunch of defects he has. And that's a good thing.
I was diagnosed late in life - in my mid-to-late 40s - with ADHD. Even though I had completed two advanced degrees and worked hard at a job/career and many other things, I was very often cross with myself for being disorganized and lazy-minded (what I had labelled my scattered thoughts.) But when one of my kids was diagnosed with ADHD, and recognizing the genetic component of it, I was evaluated and diagnosed. My self-criticism by then had become ingrained, and I still have to remind myself that some of that is just a habitual response, a thought-loop if you will. I can cope well enough without medication, but I cope significantly better with; I feel free to take it when I really need to. And, no, I haven't needed to today. Most days, I don't. But it's there when I need or want to. :) 

Your title is about introducing management techniques while your final question is whether to introduce the names of the potential conditions.  So I will address your last question.
I would give him some context - there are some children with a personality type that makes X, Y, Z harder for them. This is OK, nothing is wrong with them, just that they may need more help with coping, regulating, coming up with special techniques... We see that you find .... a struggle, and we want to think together of some techniques to help you out.
However, I would not give him names of conditions at this point.  They are just labels that add confusion and stigma.  One he reaches an age where he is mature enough to research these conditions on his own it will be invaluable to have this information.  For now, the focus should be on a plan to help him out rather than the label.
